# How to generate superscript with Arcade derived labels

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I would like to label features with superscript mi2 in AGOL map viewer. I've tried setting the label as `var label = " mi" + "<SUP>" + "2" + "</SUP>"` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but formatting of labels in ArcGIS Pro is poorly supported by it's ArcGIS Online equivalent. Maybe future releases will be improved.
As a workaround after you type your text `mi` then hold down your Alt key and type 253 to get a superscript two.  So your Arcade expression would be:

`var label = " mi²"`

There are various threads (have a look at this [one](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/confused-about-arcade-labeling-compatibility/m-p/570696)) to explore on the Esri Community forum that discuss this issue and I get the impression that ArcGIS Online currently has no support for formatting tags used in ArcGIS Pro.